# finding systemd unit 'owning' a running daemon process

Tags: fedora, systemd, pulseaudio

To debug a JACK/Pulseaudio issue, I want to understand when and why the pulseaudio daemon is started by systemd (on Fedora).

Using:

```
$ ps -o'pid,ppid,args' `pgrep pulse`
```

I see that the pulseaudio daemon is being started by systemd (pid=1)

```
 PID  PPID COMMAND
2738     1 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start
```

However, I was unable to find any unit-file on my system containing `pulseaudio` or even just `pulse`.

My specific questions are:

A) Is there a way to determine the systemd unit that caused the creation of a specific process (in my example output, process 2738, the PA daemon)?

B) Are there alternative approaches to find out which unit-dependency chain or other settings of systemd resulted in the invocation of `/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start`?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

> A) Is there a way to determine the systemd unit that caused the creation of a specific process (in my example output, process 2738, the PA daemon)?

Sure.  You can run `systemctl status <pid>` and systemd will find you the unit that contains that PID.  For example, on my system I find a `dnsmasq` process:

```
# ps -fe | grep dnsmasq
nobody   18834  1193  0 Aug25 ?        00:00:10 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq ...
```

Who started it?

```
# systemctl status 18834
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2015-08-25 11:07:40 EDT; 1 day 21h ago
 Main PID: 1193 (NetworkManager)
   Memory: 1.1M
   CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
           ├─ 1193 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
           ├─ 1337 /sbin/dhclient -d -q -sf /usr/libexec/nm-dhcp-helper -pf /var/run/dhclient-wlp3s0....
           ├─18682 /usr/libexec/nm-openvpn-service
           ├─18792 /usr/sbin/openvpn --remote ovpn-phx2.redhat.com 443 tcp --nobind --dev redhat --de...
           └─18834 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --...
```

I also have a `pulseaudio` process:

```
# ps -fe | grep pulseaudio
lars      2948     1  0 Aug25 ?        00:06:20 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start
```

Running `systemctl status 2948`, I see:

```
● session-3.scope - Session 3 of user lars
   Loaded: loaded (/run/systemd/system/session-3.scope; static; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/system/session-3.scope.d
           └─50-After-systemd-logind\x2eservice.conf, 50-After-systemd-user-sessions\x2eservice.conf, 50-Description.conf, 50-SendSIGHUP.conf, 50-Slice.conf
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2015-08-25 11:09:23 EDT; 1 day 21h ago
   CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-3.scope
```

This tells me the `pulseaudio` was started from my desktop login session, rather than explicitly via systemd.

Comment: I wanted to find a way to script this. `systemctl` has a `--property` option for selecting which unit properties to show, but unfortunately this works only with `show` not `status`, and `show` doesn't work with PIDs. The best I could come up with is:
`systemctl status -n0 $PID 2>/dev/null | head -n1 | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: @NeilMayhew See `ps -o unit` answer by Lukáš. Assuming you're on a modern system and it works, it's a beautiful thing.

Answer (score 16):

By the way you can ask ps to show corresponding systemd unit.

```
[lnykryn@notas]$ ps -o'pid,ppid,args,unit' `pgrep pulse`
  PID  PPID COMMAND                     UNIT
 1345     1 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start session-1.scope
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, and I notice that `man ps` says "if systemd support has been included." So I assume it's system-dependent.

Comment: Awesome! And would be even better with the underused `ps -C CMD` option, e.g., `ps -o pid,args,unit -C pulseaudio`.

Answer (score 4):

Note, a process having a parent PPID of 1 *does not mean* it was created by systemd.
Any process that loses its parent process is automatically re-assigned the parent 1.

You can see the hierarchy of systemd processes with

```
systemctl status
```

which shows for me amongst other stuff (edited):

```
CGroup: 
|-1 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --system --deserialize 17
|-system.slice
`-user.slice
  `-user-1000.slice
    |-session-66.scope
    | |-4108 /bin/dbus-launch --autolaunch ...
    | |-4109 /bin/dbus-daemon --fork ...
    | `-5985 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my fallacy about PPID==1. Actually I knew that already and just forgot about it when thinking about this question.